# Converting modified strtok tokens back into the original string's "syntax"

Tags: c, string, strtok

Is there a way after you've split a string into tokens to convert these tokens *back* into the original string (with punctuation, and original case-sensitivity)?

I'm fairly certain strcat will be invoked, but what would be a good method to maintain the original string's punctuation & case-sensitivity?

Assume that I need to modify each and every token individually before concatenating them back into the original string's structure.

Edit: The title has been reworded & clarified, I hope.

```
char* msg = malloc(10000);
char* msg2 = malloc(10000);
char* buffer;
char buffer2[10000];

printf("input: \n");
fgets(msg, 9999, stdin);

msg2 = strdup(msg);
buffer = strtok(msg2, " ;,.!?\n");
Node* ptr; // assume this is initialized to a linked list containing 2 strings per node (str, str2)
while (buffer) {

        for (int i = 0; i < strlen(buffer); i++) { //strcmp is case-sensitive
            if (isalpha(buffer[i])) {
                buffer[i] = tolower(buffer[i]);
            }
        }
        while (ptr) {
            if ((ptr != NULL) && (strcmp(ptr->str, ptr->str2) != 0)) {
                buffer = ptr->str2; // modifies the token 
                break;
            }
    }
    ptr = ptr->next;
    }
    strcat(buffer2, " "); // this will concatenate the modified tokens back together with spaces
    strcat(buffer2, buffer); // but I lose the original string's structure (i.e.: punctuation, case-sensitivity)
    buffer = strtok(NULL, " ;,.!?\n");

    printf("%s", buffer2); // so how should I get the original string's structure back with the modified tokens?
```

Comment: Um... Save a copy before you split it?

Comment: @KenWhite I need to modify each token individually though so that wouldn't do me much good I think. Plus I do have a copy saved: `char* msg` is untouched.

Comment: The problem is, unless you are breaking the words on a single delimiter, or saving the delimiter between each word, there is no way to recreate the string because you don't know which delimiter was there originally. If you just want to write the tokens back out with a space in between, see `sprintf`.

Comment: @Sleepless, I must be confused what you are asking, why not `printf("%s", msg);`?? You are comparing a lower-case of each token with the elements of a list and concatenating `buffer` with `buffer2` with a space in between, but then what?

Comment: @Sleepless: since you have the original in `msg` and are splitting the copy pointed at by `msg2`, you can recover the original from `msg`.  Since `strtok()` doesn't tell you which character it found to mark the end of a token and does overwrite the character with a null, if you have not got a copy to work from, you're hosed — nothing doing.  Since you are already working on a copy, what's the problem?

Comment: You asked how to convert it back to **the original string**. The *original string* would not have any changes. Making modifications would mean it's no longer the **original string**. If you mean to ask something else, then ask something else.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin First I'm comparing the lower-case of each token with element `str` of a linked list node, and if it matches, then I change the token to the element `str2` of the linked list node. After I'm done comparing & changing every token, I want to concatenate these modified tokens back into the "structure" or "syntax" of the original string.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Sorry, I phrased my title & question poorly — see my comment directed to David C. Rankin for clarification (I hope).

Comment: If you want to know what was between the original tokens, you'll have to either abandon `strtok()` — probably a good idea — or look at the original string and work out what the separators were, etc.  I am simply unsure why you have a problem since you've kept the original string.  Anyway, it sounds to me like you should be using `strcspn()` instead of `strtok()`; it won't clobber your string and gives you offsets into the string which apply equally to the original and the copy.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `strtok()` and want to access the original string later, please keep a copy of the original string, since strtok() will destroy the original string.

```
// we have char *st ;

char *tem = malloc(strlen(st)+1);
strcpy(tem, st);
```

Now you can access tem as original string later.

Comment: There is a very thin line between an answer and a comment. You are the ultimate judge, but you want to always ask "am I providing a direct answer to the question asked, or am I providing a work-around?" No harm done, but I would have reached the opposite conclusion.

Comment: Sorry. So you mean I should provide a direct answer to the problem?

Comment: No, I meant it was a close call whether what you posted was an actual answer of whether it would have been better as a comment. If what you are posting can fit it a comment and isn't a direct solution to the question, then it is probably better as a comment. Like I said, no harm done, just be mindful of the difference.

Comment: `sizeof` is wrong here. This code will allocate space for an integer, then copy the string into that space.

Comment: You fail to realize that `sizeof(strlen..)` (and `sizeof(strlen..+1)`, `sizeof(strlen(..)+10000)` and so on) always gives back `sizeof(size_t)`.